# Generate lambda class for generic type variable using reflection

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I am attempting to use Java interfaces as mixins in some high-level wrapper for type `D`.

```
interface WrapsD {
    D getWrapped();
}

interface FeatureA extends WrapsD {
    default ...
}

interface FeatureB extends WrapsD  {
    default ...
}

abstract class DWrapperFactory<T extends WrapsD> {
    protected T doWrap(D d) {
        return () -> d; // <- does not work
    }
}

interface FeatureAB extends FeatureA, FeatureB {
}

class ProducingDWithFeatureAB extends DWrapperFactory<FeatureAB> {
    protected FeatureAB doWrap(D d) {
        return () -> d; // <- has to repeat this
    }
}
```

As seen in `ProducingDWithFeatureAB`, `doWrap` has to be implemented in each sub-class even though the body is identical. (One more example of why Java generics is really broken.)

Since I already need to create concrete classes like `ProducingDWithFeatureAB` for other reasons and code exists in the JRE to sythesize lambda classes, it should be possible to write `doWrap` only once using reflection. I want to know how it can be done.

(`doWrap` used to be implemented using anonymous inner classes implementing the interface, which is even more biolderplate.)

Comment: Generic types are erased at compile time due to type erasure. So the generic method/lambda you are going for may not be possible in this instance.

Comment: @callyalater I already have to create a sub-class for each different `T` so the type is guaranteed to be available via reflection. I am just trying to avoid copying the implementation of `fun()` again and again just to make the types work...

Comment: What kind of code in anonymous local classes do you want to replace?

Comment: how do you expect it to behave?

Comment: Could you provide sample code of what you are trying to refactor? I don't see how a generic `T` could be implemented by an anonymous class, except with an unchecked cast (and then the problem would actually lie there).

Comment: I rephrased the question. Hopefully it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you have to understand, is, that a method of the form

```
public Function<X,Y> fun() {
    return arg -> expr;
}
```

is desugared to the equivalent of:

```
public Function<X,Y> fun() {
    return DeclaringClass::lambda$fun$0;
}
private static Y lambda$fun$0(X arg) {
    return expr;
}
```

whereas the types `X` and `Y` are derived from the functional signature of your target interface. While the actual instance of the functional interface is generated at runtime, you need a materialized target method to be executed, which is generated by the compiler.

You can generate instances of different interfaces for a single target method reflectively, but it still requires that all these functional interfaces have the same functional signature, e.g. mapping from `X` to `Y`, which reduces the usefulness of a dynamic solution.

In your case, where all target interfaces indeed have the same functional signature, it is possible, but I have to emphasize that the whole software design looks questionable to me.

For implementing the dynamic generation, we have to desugar the lambda expression as described above and add the captured variable `d` as an additional argument to the target method. Since your specific function has no arguments, it makes the captured `d` the sole method argument:

```
protected T doWrap(D d) {
    Class<T> type=getActualT();
    MethodHandles.Lookup l=MethodHandles.lookup();
    try
    {
        MethodType fType = MethodType.methodType(D.class);
        MethodType tType = fType.appendParameterTypes(D.class);
        return type.cast(LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(l, "getWrapped",
            tType.changeReturnType(type), fType,
            l.findStatic(DWrapperFactory.class, "lambda$doWrap$0", tType), fType)
            .getTarget().invoke(d));
    }
    catch(RuntimeException|Error t) { throw t; }
    catch(Throwable t) { throw new IllegalStateException(t); }
}
private static D lambda$doWrap$0(D d) {
    return d;
}
```

You have to implement the method `getActualT()` which ought to return the right class object, which is possible if the actual subclass of `DWrapperFactory` is a proper reifiable type, as you stated. Then, the method `doWrap` will dynamically generate a proper instance of `T`, invoking the desugared lambda expression’s method with the captured value of `d`—all assuming that the type `T` is indeed a functional interface, which cannot be proven at compile time.

Note that even at runtime, the `LambdaMetafactory` won’t check whether the invariants hold, you might get errors thrown at a later time if `T` isn’t a proper functional interface (and subclass of `WrapsD`).

---

Now compare to just repeating the method

```
protected SubtypeOfWrapsD doWrap(D d) {
    return () -> d;
}
```

in each reifiable type that has to exist anyway…

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the advice. I am reevaluating this architecture. Sadly, it is the one that involves the least changes to the calling code...

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with generics; your generic example is just obfuscating the real issue.

Here's the core of the issue: lambda expressions need a *target type* that is a functional interface, and that target type must be statically known to the compiler.  Your code doesn't provide that.  For example, the following code would get the same error, for the same reason:

```
Object o = arg -> expr;
```

Here, Object is not a functional interface, and lambda expressions can only be used in a context whose type is a (compatible) functional interface.

The use of generics makes it more confusing (and I think you're also confusing yourself about how generics work), but ultimately this is going to be where this bottoms out.

Comment: Yes, I understand all of this. The problem is there's no way to tell the compiler the generic type variable `T` is a functional interface. And the root of this issue is that Java generics is implemented using type erasure instead of templating. I can guarantee that `T` will be a functional interface, so it should be possible to generate the correct synthesized class at run time using relfection. I just want to know how to do it.

Comment: No, that's not the actual problem -- it's just the next thing you're tripping over.  Even if there were a way to constrain `T` as `T extends FunctionalInterface`, that only moves the problem one step down the road -- the compiler still must know the target type _statically_ in order to generate the right instantiation code.  And that information is still erased.

Comment: Yes, I get that as well. As I mentioned in the question's commenets and the revised question, I do not expect the compiler would be able to generate the byte code for the lambda, but rather I'd synthesize the lambda class at runtime using reflection and the class meta-data which would have T as a concrete type.